# I keep getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5! How do I fix this?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, runtime-error

I keep getting the error code: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 or with random numbers instead of 5. I am trying to write a script that takes a list of test scores from the user's input, then calculates the highest score they inputted. How do I fix this?

NOTE:"scores" is my array list name and "testNum" is the amount of test scores they put in.

```
System.out.print ("Enter a set of test scores, hitting enter after each one: ");
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//   loop that will set values to the scores array until the user's set amount is reached.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
for(int x = 0; x < testNum; x += 1) //x will approach testNum until it is less than it, then stop.
{
    scores[x] = scan.nextInt();

} //working



    for(int z = 0, a = 1; z < testNum; z += 1) // attempts to find the highest number entered.
{
    if (scores[z] > scores[z + a])
    {
        a += 1;
        z -= 1; //offsets the loop's += 1 to keep the same value of z
    }
    else
    {
        if (z + a >= testNum)
        {
            System.out.println ("The highest number  was " + scores[z]);
        }
        a = 0; //resets a to try another value of scores[z].

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the size of `scores`?

Comment: Stop trying to access array element `5`.

Comment: Your title is very deceptive... I would advise asking something like 'How do I iterate an array in javascript'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've shown:

`testNum` is greater than `scores.length`.  This means that when you traverse the array by comparing your iterator (`i`) to `testNum` rather than its actual length, you will hit indexes which don't exist.

For example, let's say `testNum = 8` and `scores.length = 5`.  Then in your code, you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:5` because your loop goes through indexes 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 (remember that arrays begin at index 0) then tries to access 5, which is out of bounds (as the Exception says).

You can properly traverse an array using either of the following techniques, depending on your use case:

```
for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    //do stuff
}
```

... or ...

```
for(int score : scores) {
    //do stuff
}
```